# Почему phpDoc парсит класс, но не создает для него страницу?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Обратите внимание на 2 файла: **`Collection.php`** и **`ICollections.php`**

Структура файловой системы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Генерирую phpDocument, получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но он эти файлы видел и парсил, т.к. есть метки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не создаются html файлы для этих классов? (`Collection.php` и `ICollections.php`)**

На всякий случай выкладываю код файла Collection.php:

```
namespace App\Collections;


/**
 * Class Collection
 * @package App\Collections
 */
class Collection implements ICollections
{
    protected $typeItem;
    protected $data = [];

    public function __construct($type_items)
    {
        if (class_exists($type_items) || interface_exists($type_items)) {
            $this->typeItem = $type_items;
        } else {
            // TODO: Exception ("неизвестный тип")
            exit("Неизвестный тип для типизации коллеции");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Добавить элемент в коллекцию
     * @param object $item Объект типа, указанного при инициализации коллекции
     */
    public function add($item)
    {
        if ($this->checkType($item)) {
            $this->data[] = $item;
        } else {
            // TODO: Exception ("неподходищий тип")
            exit("Не подходит тип объекта для Коллекции");
        }
    }

    public function remove($item)
    {
        if ($this->checkType($item)) {
            foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
                if ($item == $value)
                {
                    unset($this->data[$key]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function array()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    protected function checkType($item)
    {
        if ($item instanceof $this->typeItem) 
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->typeItem;
    }
}
```